# Why am I getting Module ‘Data.CaseInsensitive’ does not export ‘CI’?

Tags: haskell

Trying to import CI as described in the docs but getting an error:
Module ‘Data.CaseInsensitive’ does not export ‘CI’

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/case-insensitive-1.2.1.0/docs/Data-CaseInsensitive.html

What is going on?

Comment: It seems their idea is to export CI as a type name, but not CI as a plain constructor. The module exports function `mk` as a “smart constructor”. You could try: `cist1 = CI.mk "abcd"`

Comment: I'm not getting any errors if I import CI as they show in their documentation. Can you give a minimal example and the exact error message that is produced?

Comment: @Hugo: how do you import this, with `import Data.CaseInsensitive(CI(CI))`? In that case you import the data constructor, but this data constructor is not exported, since the data is first validated through a "smart constructor".

Answer (score 1):

As [your answer indicates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68906566/67579) there was a collision between the `case-insensitive` package, and a custom package.

You can make use of [*package-qualified imports*](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/package_qualified_imports.html#package-qualified-imports) by enable the  [**`PackageImports`** language pragma](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/package_qualified_imports.html#extension-PackageImports), and then specify the name of the package as a string literal, so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PackageImports #-}

import "case-insensitive"           Data.CaseInsensitive  (CI)
import qualified "case-insensitive" Data.CaseInsensitive as CI
```

This thus allows working with two or more packages that export a module with the same name and thus avoid clashes. It will also give more helpful message if it turns out you did not expose that package (in your .cabal file for example).

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassed to admit this but I was using another library which doesn't expose CI from its module but has the same module name. Thanks everyone for your valuable time.